# Gauss curvature and 1st fundamental form

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

I would like to prove

$$K=\frac12g^{jk}R^{i}_{ijk}$$

I know that $$K(p)=I(R(v,w)w,v)$$

for an orthonormal basis $(v,w)$ of $T_pS$. (I want to consider a $2$-dimensional manifold, i.e. a surface)

Using a parametrisation $F:U\rightarrow V$, I find

$$
\begin{align}
I(R(v,w)w,v)
&=I(R^{l}_{ijk}v^iw^jw^k\partial_lF,v^m\partial_mF)\\
&=R^{l}_{ijk}v^iw^jw^kv^mg_{lm}\\
\end{align}$$

I think I have to use $(v,w)=(\frac{\partial_1 F}{\|\partial_1 F\|},\frac{\partial_2 F}{\|\partial_2 F\|})$, if it was orthogonal in the first place... So I do not really know how to move on.

Thanks for your attention. I'd be very grateful for some help!

Comment: Are you aware/able to show that the value of the expression $g^{jk}R^i{}_{ijk}$ is independent of the choice of coordinates?

Comment: Yes, using that the riemannian metric / first fundamental form is. therefore christoffel symbols and also R. How does this help in the further calculation?

Comment: Found the solution on my own. However, your comment did not help.

Comment: You can always choose coordinates so that $\partial_1F,\partial_2F$ are orthonormal at $p$. Once you show $K(p)=\frac{1}{2}g^{ij}(p)R^i{}_{ijk}(p)$ in those coordinates, it also holds in any other coordinates. This isn't the only way to proceed, of course.